# Polymorphic Misunderstand

Tags: java, exception, polymorphism

When i call s1.dub(7) or s2.dub(7) it doesn't work
,but calling it with a string like s2.dub("9") works and prints the doubled string

Could any one tell me why?

Here's the code

```
interface Inter {
  int number();
}
abstract class Abs {
static int foo = 12;
    int number() { return 5; }
    abstract int ace();
}
final class Sub extends Super {
    Sub(int bar) { foo = bar; }
    public int number() { return 10; }
    int ace() { return 13; }
    int dub(int i) { return 2 * i; }
}
public class Super extends Abs implements Inter {
    public int number() { return 11; }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Super s1 = new Super();
        Super s2 = new Sub(16);
        //System.out.println(s1.dub(7));     //doesn't work
        //System.out.println(s2.dub(7));     //doesn't work
        //System.out.println(s1.dub("7"));   //works giving 77
        //System.out.println(s2.dub("7"));   //works giving 77
    }
    int twice(int x) { return 2 * x; }
    public int thrice(int x) { return 3 * x; }
    int ace() { return 1; }
    String dub(String s) { return s + s; }
 }
```

Comment: I'm a bit tired, but I think this should not even compile?

Comment: Edited Now, recheck it!

Comment: s1.dub(7) won't compile as you are passing an int value while the only dub method in Super object expect a String. s2.dub(7) will also not compile as, while you are creating a Sub object which does have a method that expect an int, you are keeping it reference as a Super which, again, only have a dub method that expect a String. That being said, you should also be able to understand why s1.dub("7") and s2.dub("7") does compile.

Comment: Also I suggest using more specific words than "work" when writing a question. You should've indicated that the code does not compile in your question.

Comment: Thank you, it was my fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very easy.. you class Super defines a method:

```
String dub(String s) { return s + s; }
```

in your main method you instantiate Super:

```
Super s1 = new Super(); // this has a dub( String ) method
```

then you try to call this method (dub) passing a integer, instead of a string:

```
System.out.println(s1.dub(7)); // s1.dub(...) takes a String, not a number
```

EDIT: This code should not compile, or run, because you are assigning both instances to the super class Super (which does not define a dub(int) method).

Not sure how you are getting exceptions?

Thank you @Jean-FrançoisSavard - I totally missed that!

EDIT2: The original question was modified and no longer indicates that an exception is thrown, which makes sense as the code should not compile at all.

EDIT3: (last one, due to original question changing)

```
System.out.println(s1.dub(7)); //- this will never work unless you change your class' definition

System.out.println(s2.dub(7)); //- will work if you also change the following line:
```

from:

```
Super s2 = new Sub(16);
```

to:

```
Sub s2 = new Sub(16);
```

Comment: *"takes a String, not a number"* Then it should not compiles ? OP is talking about an exception. The second part of your answer is also wrong

Comment: You are correct! It doesn't compile on my compiler - both lines where you pass in a number have errors when I try to compile it. How are you compiling this code?

Comment: I suggest you delete the answer and continue the discussion in comments under the question. That way you'll avoid downvotes and will also help other to understand the question as they are more likely to look for information about the issue in question comments rather than answer's comment.

Comment: But it works with 

     System.out.println(s2.dub("7"));       //giving 77

and doesn't work with

     System.out.println(s2.dub(7));

Comment: Can you please define "does not work"? Do you mean it throws an exception during runtime or does it not compile?

Comment: It doesn't compile.